# "whom,them" vs "that, which " as appositive

Tags: appositives

1. Sixty people, **most of whom** were females, liked the party.
2. Sixty people, **most of them** were females, liked the party.
3. The animal, **which is sick**, needs treatments.
4. The animal, **that is sick**, needs treatments.

Are all of those sentences correct?  If any of them is wrong, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

These would be my approaches the first sentence:

> Sixty people, most of whom were females, liked the party
>  
>   Sixty people, most of them female, liked the party
>   Sixty people, mostly women, liked the party.

I am not prepared to even consider the second sentence because, without context, it is needlessly complex. here is a more sensible way of writing it.

> The sick animal needs treatment.

The problem with made-up sentences is that it's hard to tell whether they are unnatural because they are made-up, or unnatural because they are grammatically wrong. It would be much better to look for real examples of a particular usage using google books:

> The house is packed with people of all ages, **most of whom** do not have Parkinson's [Most of me](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=VeDVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22most%20of%20whom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbwMrM7N7OAhVBBBoKHYYwAa8Q6AEIJTAD#v=onepage&q=%22most%20of%20whom%22&f=false)
>
> I've provided a very supportive book introduction, so **most of them** feel confident to try reading the book. [making the most of small groups](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=P3vNOD3FR3wC&pg=PA149&dq=%22most%20of%20them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUoriA7t7OAhWIORoKHVdEAnYQ6AEISTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22most%20of%20them%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

I would say all four of your sentences are correct and understandable.

> Sixty people, most of whom were females, liked the party.

is fine.

> Sixty people, most of them were females, liked the party.

is slightly awkward but

> Sixty people liked the party and most of them were females.
>   Sixty people liked the party. Most of them were females.

would sound more natural.

Commas are not necessary in your last two sentences

> The animal which is sick needs treatment.
>   The animal that is sick needs treatment.

and treatment**s** should be singular even if the animal needs more than one type of treatment.

Comment: #Peter "Sixty people liked the party, most of them were females " This sentence seems to be incorrect!  I am copying a rule from a website - As follows :

A quantity phrase with whom is placed at the front of the
modifying clause and then the clause is placed directly
after the noun it modifies.


"California has a lot of visitors , most of whom visit
Disneyland.
"

Comment: _Sixty people liked the party, most of them were females._ is a comma-splice.

Comment: By using "them" the phrase becomes independent, either a coordinating conjunction or a new sentence is necessary to stay away from a comma splice.  That's why using "them" sounds better at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The words in all four sentences could be seen as correct, depending on your meaning. I dislike using the sterile and biological term "females" to refer to women, but leaving that aside for the moment:

> Sixty people, most of whom were females, liked the party.

This is a correct dependent clause where "whom" refers to people.

> Sixty people, most of them were females, liked the party.

This is a little abrupt-sounding because "Most of them were females" is a complete sentence on its own. Inserting a complete sentence as a parenthetical in another sentence isn't impossible. In writing, it would be better to set it off with em dashes, though.

Your last two questions on *that* vs. *which* are more interesting. *Which* can be used to introduce an independent or a dependent clause. *That* can only be used to introduce a dependent clause. Most style guides would tell you *not* to use *which* to introduce a dependent clause. The commas matter, too. If it's an independent clause, it needs the commas, but the commas are technically incorrect in the one with *that*. Your examples are especially interesting, though, because they are a good example of exactly when it makes a difference when you use *that* or *which*. Here is how I would be most likely to read the following:

> The animal, which is sick, needs treatments.

I would be most likely to take this to mean that a specific animal needs treatments *because* it is sick.

On the other hand, I would read the following differently:

> The animal that is sick needs treatments.

I would take this to mean that the specific animal that happens to be sick needs treatments, but the animals that are well don't need treatments.